# TemplateMatching using EMGU CV

Tags: c#, emgucv

I'm trying to use `TemplateMatching` from EMGU CV in order to find(match) a template image in a source image.

Below is the code (sample taken from Stack Overflow)

```
public static void TemplateMatch()
{
    Image<Bgr, Byte> sourceImg = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(@"D:\ImageA.png");
            Image<Bgr, Byte> templateImg = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(@"D:\ImageB.png"); 
    Image<Bgr, byte> lastImage = sourceImg.Copy();
    using (Image<Gray, float> resultImg = sourceImg.MatchTemplate(templateImg, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.TemplateMatchingType.CcorrNormed))
    {
        double[] minVal, maxVal;
        System.Drawing.Point[] minLocations, maxLocations;
        resultImg.MinMax(out minVal, out maxVal, out minLocations, out maxLocations);
        if (maxVal[0] > 0.9)
        {
            Rectangle match = new Rectangle(maxLocations[0], templateImg.Size);
            lastImage.Draw(match, new Bgr(Color.Red), 3);  
        }
        ImageViewer.Show(lastImage);
    }
}
```

But the disadvantage is that if I try to match a template image of different size with the source image, then there is no result.

I have been suggested to loop over the scales of the image in order to find the match. But I'm not sure how to do it in C#.

Here my aim is to find image A (template image) in image B (source image) using template matching in C# irrespective of the scaling and resolution.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @MohamadMousheimish: thank you for wanting to edit here. I wonder if I could point out that inline `code formatting` is only for code snippets and small pieces of system IO - it is not appropriate a general highlighter. Proper nouns (such as C#) are not themselves code.